# jsRender optional model properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jsrender

I'd like to have my jsRender templates optionally include an "options" property to provide optional fall-backs if a property is not included; specifically rendering one element if the "options" property is included, or another if it is not.  Everything works fine if the model passed in contains the property in question, but even `{{if typeof ~options.someOption !== 'undefined'}}` gives me `Error: Cannot read property 'someOption' of undefined.`

Has anyone dealt with this?  If so, how do you handle properties of the model passed in that do no exist?

**EDIT:** This question is really about how to handle missing properties of a model.  Given a model with properties A and B, if property B is missing from the model but it is referenced in the template, how can I prevent error messages and handle it's absence elegantly?

Comment: Is this more along the lines of what you are looking to do, [link]http://borismoore.github.com/jsviews/demos/step-by-step/01_rendering-and-linking.html)

Comment: Although this is cool it is more focused on jsViews and databinding.  My issue is more core to rendering and how a template is selected/rendered.

Comment: You can make sure you create a model that your models inherit from.  In Backbone, you would create a model and set it's default values and then every new model you create based on this model, is guaranteed to have all of the properties even though you may not supply them.  var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({ defaults: { "prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2" });  then to create a new model.  var model = new Model({"prop1": "new value"}); model now has both prop1 and prop2.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the fact that in Javascript things that don't exist evaluate as "undefined", which equates to false in conditional statements, and wrap an "if" around the containing object and property you are trying to access.  So, to use your example, you would go like

`{{if options}}{{if options.someOption}}{{:options.someOption}}{{/if}}{{/if}}`

If both options and someOption exist, the template will render with options.SomeOption.  Otherwise it will do nothing.